# How to make container expand up instead of down when component added?

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox, position, styled-components

I have a React component that asks user to upload profile photo. In the same view, the user can see a greyed out 'next' button. When the photo is uploaded and displayed, the user sees a horizontal scrolling bar to adjust photo size that comes between the photo and `next` button. My goal is to keep the `next` button in view at all times but also keep all elements of the component in the same order. Right now, a user has to scroll down to see the 'next' once the image is loaded. I've been experimenting with `flex` and `position` and even a ternary in the JSX to add `paddingBottom` when `!isLoading`. Can someone give a good direction so that the user doesn't have to scroll down to see the `next' button`?

Here is my component:

```
import React, { useContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import Typography from 'components/Typography';
// import { useMediaQuery } from 'beautiful-react-hooks';
import { medium } from 'constants/mediaQueries';
import AppButton from 'components/AppButton';
import useFetcher from 'hooks/useFetcher';
import { getMeApi } from 'utils/apiRoutes';
import Loader from 'components/Loader';
import routePaths from 'containers/Router/routePaths';
import { useHistory, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import { UserContext } from 'containers/context/UserContext';
import checkmarkImage from 'assets/images/checkmark.svg';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import BackArrowGrid from 'components/Auth/BackArrowGrid';
import UploadImageInput from 'components/UploadImageInput';
import { setPlainLogo, setInitialLogo } from '../../store/header/actions';

// const MOBILE = 250;
// const DESKTOP = 356;

const Container = styled.div`
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: pink solid 2px;
`;

const ButtonContainer = styled.div`
  margin-top: 32px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  div {
    margin-bottom: 16px;
  }

  img {
    margin-left: 8px;
  }
`;

const Title = styled(Typography)`
  font-size: 40px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-bottom: 64px;

  @media (min-width: ${medium}) {
    margin-bottom: 64px;
  }
`;

const ButtonContent = styled.span`
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
`;

const Form = styled.div`
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-self: flex-end;
  border: yellow solid 2px;
  .empty {
    display: none;
  }

  @media (min-width: ${medium}) {
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: auto;

    .empty {
      display: block;
      width: 118px;
    }
  }
`;

const UploadPicture = () => {
  const { fetcher, error, isLoading } = useFetcher();
  const { setUserFromLogin } = useContext(UserContext);
  const history = useHistory();
  const location = useLocation();
  // const isDesktop = useMediaQuery(`(min-width: ${medium})`);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [image, setImage] = useState({});

  const uploadImage = async () => {
    const result = await fetcher({
      url: getMeApi,
      method: 'POST',
      body: {
        photo: image.croppedImage.source,
      },
    });
    if (result.errors) {
      return;
    }
    setUserFromLogin(result.user);
    if (location.profile) {
      history.push(routePaths.Profile);
    } else {
      history.push(routePaths.Welcome);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(setPlainLogo());
    return () => dispatch(setInitialLogo());
  }, []);

  const onPictureChange = newImage => {
    setImage(prevImage => ({
      ...prevImage,
      ...newImage,
    }));
  };

  return (
    <>
      <BackArrowGrid>
        <Container>
          <Title h1>Profile photo</Title>
          <Form>
            <div className="empty">&nbsp;</div>
            <UploadImageInput
              onChange={onPictureChange}
              image={image}
              placeholder={
                "Upload a profile photo. This is how you'll appear to other Color TV users."
              }
              height={356}
              width={356}
              horizontalPadding={60}
              aspect={1}
              round
            />
            <ButtonContainer>
              {error && (
                <Typography error>
                  Error while uploading the image, please try again.
                </Typography>
              )}

              <AppButton
                primary={!!image.croppedImage}
                disabled={isLoading || !image.croppedImage}
                onClick={uploadImage}
                noBorder
              >
                <ButtonContent>
                  {isLoading ? (
                    <Loader className="center" size={30} />
                  ) : (
                    'Next'
                  )}
                  {!isLoading && !!image.croppedImage && (
                    <img src={checkmarkImage} alt="checkmark_icon" />
                  )}
                </ButtonContent>
              </AppButton>
            </ButtonContainer>
          </Form>
        </Container>
      </BackArrowGrid>
    </>
  );
};

export default UploadPicture;
```

Since this component is part of a larger code base, I'm not sure how to run a snippet of it but here are 2 photos - before and after. Once the photo is uploaded, the `next` button drops out of view because the slider component is added in. I want to `next` button to stay in view no matter how the browser size.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you set a fiddle with the html/css output? It's quite difficult to know what's happening from this code

Comment: Can you please provide the code in stackblitz or in here code section so that we can see the actual output. That will help us to resolve your issue there and give it back to you.

Comment: If the component in question is part of a large code base, how do you get it working in a sandbox environment? Sorry but this is my first developer gig.

Comment: Did you see my edit?